# Count hashmap elements with condition for members?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm new with Swift and I'm currently programming a to-do app.

```
let todos: [Todo] = [
    
    Todo(category: "Business", todo: "Daily meeting with team", done: true),
    Todo(category: "Business", todo: "Pretend to be productive", done: false),
    Todo(category: "Personal", todo: "Pay for rent", done: true),
    Todo(category: "Personal", todo: "Lunch with Emma", done: false)
]
    
let todoCategories: [TodoCategory] = [
    
    TodoCategory(category: "Business", allTasks: [RESPONSIVE], doneTasks: [RESPONSIVE], color: 0xb230de),
    TodoCategory(category: "Personal", allTasks: [RESPONSIVE], doneTasks: [RESPONSIVE], color: 0x4275df)
]
```

The members "allTasks" and "doneTasks" should be made responsive. But how can I count "todos" with a condition for "done"?

Like

```
var allTasks = 0
var doneTasks = 0

if todos.done{

    allTasks += 1
    doneTasks += 1
}else{

    allTasks += 1
}
```

and then paste those numbers as "allTasks" and "doneTasks" into todoCategories.

Comment: couldn't be able to understand it. make it simple

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed I have two arrays. first array [category: string, todo: string, done: bool], second array [category: string, allTasks: int, doneTasks: int]. in the first array are todos with the member "done". now I wish to fill "doneTasks" in the second array with all todos from the first array with the member done = false. you understand?

Comment: let allDone = todos.map{$0.done == true}.count

Comment: let allUnDone = todos.map{$0.done == false}.count

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed and how do I add it to the second array?

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed I get an error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'Int'.

Comment: still i dont knnow what u want ... do you want differentiate the object where done is true and false

Comment: let allDone = todos.filter{$0.done == true}   this is array of todo done task

Comment: let allDone = todos.filter{$0.done == false}  this is array of undone tasks